As a PhD graduate determined to become a professor (in machine learning), what is most important for: 1. Finding a postdoc; 2. Doing a good postdoc
So I have a good PhD track in machine learning (>200 citations and good papers), and I'm very determined to stay in academia (I love teaching, learning, researching, advising students and pretty much nearly every aspect of academia).
I'm now looking for a postdoc, with partial funding (I got an award that gets appended to whatever salary I get in a postdoc position). Some PIs are more aligned with my interests, but seem too 'new' (not many citations, no indication of students who went on to academia etc.), while others seem highly cited with high h-index etc., but are slightly less aligned with my interests (and are also likely to not be available according to their websites).
I'm a bit confused as to what I should be putting my emphasis on when looking for a postdoc advisor, and what I should be focused on doing throughout (the reason this is not posted as a separate question is because I suppose this will influence the answer to the first). Should I prefer someone in my precise field and not worry much about their lack of experience? Is it perhaps better if I do something adjacent (less interesting to me, but still close to my field) with someone who is much more experienced and cited? Perhaps all that matters is what I, personally, end up coming up with and publishing, and not the particular PI?
I'm determined to become a professor as a career. What are the criteria that really matter?
Thanks.

There is no guaranteed path. You apply fairly widely, evaluate whatever options arise, and move on with life. Different opportunities have different pluses and minuses.

What I'm trying to understand here is whether your question is really at its heart different from any given collection of our other questions about (1) How to have a successful postdoc and (2) What one should be doing to build a portfolio that can land you a faculty position. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-expected-of-a-postdoc. If you want a faculty job, Google departments where you'd be willing to work and look at their assistant professors' CV's.

it is also field dependent. In some fields, high-impact publication is only possible in famous lab
