# What is academic degree after PhD?

Tags: phd, postdocs, science, degree, international

Does your country have any academic degrees after the PhD? If yes, what is it called and how graduating this degree?

Additionally, what is a Post-Doc? Is it a degree or something else? I have seen some people refer to a post-doc in their CV as they would a degree. Is this acceptable?

Comment: I'm closing your main question as it's a duplicate of a previous one. As for your question concerning what is a postdoc, you can have a look at: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2173/102

Answer (score 8):

In general, a PhD is the highest degree you can get. A postdoc is simply a research position that is not permanent, i.e. no fixed contract or tenure. There are some exceptions, for example in the German system where you can get your Habilitation, which is a degree after you get your PhD. But in most systems there is nothing beyond a PhD in terms of degrees.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In our home country we have it. In Mongolia is so called Doctor of Science (ScD). PhD and ScD is very different degree by our rule.

Answer (score 2):

Many countries have higher degrees than the PhD.

[In the UK](http://www.uea.ac.uk/calendar/section3/regs%28awards%29/doctor-of-laws,-of-letters-and-of-science), there's

- Litt.D Doctor of Letters / Literature
- DSc Doctor of Science
- LL.d Doctor of Laws
- D.D. Doctor of Divinity

Each of these typically requires the submission of a body of work - a research portfolio - together with a critique of the work. Or they may be awarded as honorary degrees; see the links above for the requirements for the degrees from the University of East Anglia (Litt.D, DSc, LL.d), and the University of Oxford (D.D.), accordingly.

A post-doc is just an academic research job that's typically done after attaining a PhD. It's not a degree in its own right

Comment: Thanks for answer. It was interesting to read about different Doctor degrees in different country.

Answer (score 0):

As @Paul Hiemstra pointed out, the highest degree level is a Doctorate (Dr) however, with this in mind, there are different academic titles that you can gain if you work at a University or high-educational institute. Here are a few:

- Senior Lecturer (Usually appointed to a academic with a level of experience, this is usually how many years they have been at a University).

  - Master Lecturer (This is usually a rank about a Senior Lecturer)
  - Reader (This is someone who usually has a vast amount of knowledge and a strong academic background who is employed by the University not so much to lecturer, but, to carry out research for the university).
  - Professor (*I believe this title is different in the US* but this title is given to an academic who has an outstanding background in research and has published books, received a lot of funding for the particular University.) A Professorship is not something that can be studied for, it is something that is achieved and you are selected for by a special panel.

You can find more about titles [here](http://euro.ecom.cmu.edu/titles/titlebook.htm)

Comment: Thanks for very detailed answer. I am agree with you that Professor is academic person who have own space in any kind of science research field.

Comment: This doesn't answer the quesstion. It's also restricted to the UK; other countries use different terms and/or use some of these terms in different ways. It also seems to be based on a misunderstanding: you say that a reader is employed "not so much to lecture"  but even lecturers spend the majority of their time on research at the older, research-based universities. I've never heard of a "master lecturer".